# How to create the matrix attached that has 2x2 blocks in its diagonal and a square outlining them?

Tags: matrices, draw

I am struggling to create the matrix in the picture attached using Latex. I have tried using commands like \hline but the matrix ends up looking messy as the line goes all the way across.

Edit: To clarify, I am looking for each block to have a square outline.

[image: A matrix with 2x2 blocks in its diagonal up to a certain point where, there after, there is only zeros. All the blank space in the matrix is just zeroes.]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and see the [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  when asking a question. So that people have a starting point.

Comment: Use Ti*k*Z's `\matrix`: each entry is itself a node, so it is possible to draw `(A-1-1.north west)rectangle(A-2-2.south eaast)`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this like you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[ \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{\mkern-5mu}c@{\,}cc*{2}{@{\;}c}@{}}%
\noalign{\vskip 1.5ex}
  \fbox{\,$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
  \end{matrix}$\,}
 \\[-0.4pt]
  & \hskip-0.4pt\fbox{\,$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0
  \end{matrix}$\,}\\[-0.5ex]
   & & \;\ddots \\[-2.2ex]
   & & & \;\ddots \\[-0.5ex]
   & & & & \fbox{\,$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0
  \end{matrix}$\,}\\
 & & & & &0 \\[-1.5ex]
 & & & & & & \ddots \\[-1ex]
 & & & & & & & 0 \bigstrut[b]
\end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: or even this variant:

```
\[ \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}l@{}c@{\mkern-5mu}c@{\,}rc*{2}{@{\;}c}@{}}%
\noalign{\vskip 1.5ex}
  \fbox{\,$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
  \end{matrix}$\,}
 \\[-0.4pt]
  & \hskip-0.4pt\fbox{\,$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 
  \end{matrix}$\,} & & & \text{\LARGE 0} \\[-0.5ex]
   & & \;\ddots \\[-2.2ex]
   & & & \;\ddots \\[-0.5ex]
   &\text{\LARGE 0} & & & \fbox{\,$\begin{matrix}
  0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0
  \end{matrix}$\,}\\
 && & & &0 \\[-1.5ex]
 & & & & & & \ddots \\[-1ex]
 & & & & & & & 0 \bigstrut[b]
\end{array}\right)
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this only, or do you also want the box around the blocks ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0  & 1  & &  & & & & &\\
-1 & 0 & &  & & & & &\\
   &   & 0  & 1 & &  & & & \\
   &   & -1 & 0 & &  & & &  \\
   &   &  &  & \ddots &  & &   \\
   &   &  &  &   & 0  & 1 & & &   \\
   &  & &  &   & -1 & 0 & & & \\
   &  & &  &   &  &  & 0 & & \\
   &  & &  &   &  &  & & \ddots & \\
   &  & &  &   &  &  & & & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```